# The precise meaning of the term 'antiderivative'

Tags: calculus, integration, terminology

I have been helping a friend prepare a calculus curriculum for a high school course, and I've encountered some apparent ambiguity concerning the precise meaning of the term 'antiderivative'. It arose from the following candidate problem:

**True/False**: If F is an antiderivative of f over an interval I, then F'(x) is equal to f(x) for every value x in the interval I *except values of x where f is discontinuous*

My inclination is to say True, but I'm concerned about the statement concerning discontinuities. (The emphasis is mine).

I thought of the relationship between the function $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 \quad if \quad x<0 \\ +1 \quad if \quad x>0 \end{cases}$$ and the function $$ F(x) = |x| $$ Clearly F'(x)=f(x) for any value except x=0, and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=F(b)-F(a)$ appears to hold for any choice of integration limits as I would expect for an antiderivative. However, I recall that by reference to the [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), f(x) cannot strictly be the derivative of any function because it does not satisfy the intermediate value property. Is it proper to say that F(x) is the antiderivative of f(x) *except* at x=0, in the manner the original problem I give implies, or is it instead proper to say that f(x) has no antiderivative *because* of its jump discontinuity, as the Darboux theorem seems to imply? If the latter is better, then what should I call F(x)? 'The function which is the antiderivative for f(x) over any interval not including x=0'? The indefinite integral of f(x), but not the antiderivative? I appreciate in advance any help those better informed than I may provide.

Comment: I didn't read your post because, if it had anything to do with the title, the antiderivative of $f$ is just the function you had to take the derivative of to get $f$. Because the derivatives of constants are zero, it won't be unique.

Comment: At points $x$ where $f$ is discontinuous, the function $F$ whose derivative is $f$ everywhere else must be undifferentiable at $x$. Thus no $F'$ can equal $f$ at that point, necessitating the italicized exception.

Comment: I understand that F' cannot equal f at x=0 for multiple reasons (f is not defined or continuous there, and F is not differentiable there). My question is about terminology: is it proper to call F an antiderivative of f if F'(x)=f(x) _almost_ everywhere in an interval, or is the term strictly reserved for a function that meets the condition everywhere?

Comment: In the case you gave, $F(x)=|x|$ is an antiderivative of the given $f$ because at every point $x$, either $F'(x)=f(x)$ or $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Comment: Another way is to look at equality of functions almost everywhere. In most cases, that's the type of equality one cares about. With that, you can define an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ as any function such that $F^\prime(x)=f(x)$ for almost all $x$. In other words, it doesn't matter what happens on a set of measure zero. If you want to extend the notion of derivative and antiderivative, I recommend you also look at the definition using the theory of distribution.